# Activities Overview Hot Corner and file drag on it (non-optimal location of window thumbnails)

Tags: nautilus, mouse, gnome-shell, drag-and-drop, activities-overview

I use **Activities Overview Hot Corner** to drag-n-drop files to background windows from nautilus window. But I don't understand why when i use **Overview Hot Corner** with clean mouse or with <kbd>Super/Win</kbd> button windows thumbnails bricks looks OK and use all useful part of the screen:

[image]

In this case I do not need to peer to any window thumbnail to drag the file to the target window. All window have maximum size in this grid case.

But when i drag file to this corner, i mostly see another picture:

[image]

Take a look on unused part of a screen on the right! It is logical to assume and it is visible on an eye that miniatures in this case much have less size.

**Not critical, but it gives discomfort to the eye.**
This is a bug or i do something wrong?

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors set up?

Comment: No, one single. On screen Dash-to-Dock Extension, but I test it without - was same behavior.

Comment: It looks like you also have Dash-to-**Panel** enabled. What happens if you disable it?

Comment: I tried disabling all extensions. BTW I tried same behavior on another laptop where extensions was not installed at all.